# Ajax Response Half Evaluated

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My ajax response seems to evaluate some of the html, but not all of it.

Example:
This is the code that replaces a div with the response from the request

```
eval(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML-xmlhttp.responseText);
```

This is the response that is plugged in

```
<Button type="button" onclick="alert("'test'")>test</button>
```

Basically my problem is that nothing happens when I click that button.
I can't get other functions besides alert to work, and I can't get different functions to work either

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: That code won't replace a div with the response. It will subtract one string from another and produce a number (probably `NaN`) which it will then try to `eval` (if you are using `eval`, you are doing something wrong).

Comment: The second piece of code won't work either, the attribute value is terminated by the second `"` so it reads `alert(` which will error.

Comment: Why is this not a real question? Obviously it is a real question to the asker.

Comment: Instead of blaming a newbie and voting him down, you'd better help him :(

Comment: @Saeed Neamati — You're right! Clearly I should have pointed out the problems with the question and not just … oh wait. I did.

Comment: @Quentin - unless you voted this down, I think the comment from saeed was not directed at you...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `=` sign instead of `-` to assign the response text to your element. Also instead of `onclick="alert("'test'")`, use `onclick="alert('test')"`.